# css style not working on aspx but working on html

Tags: html, asp.net

why does this css works when i code it with html and stay checked when i select the radio button but not when i use aspx

```
.btn-check:checked + .btn-secondary, .btn-check:active + .btn-secondary, .btn-secondary:active, .btn-secondary.active, .show > .btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #80D2DA;
  border-color: #80D2DA;
}
```

aspx code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-6 pt-lg-0 pt-2">
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" class="btn-check"  GroupName="Testing" Text="1"  />
                   <label class="btn btn-secondary w-100 p-lg-3 p-3" for="RadioButton1">above 37&deg;C</label>
                </div>
```

Comment: Try CssClass as attribute instead of plain class

Comment: not working as well

Comment: Inspect the resulting html as it arrived at the browser, is it what you and the css expect?

Comment: it is but i want the radio button to become darker like it is pressed down but it is not working when i use in with asp but it is working when i code it in html

Answer (score 0):

Well, those button class look to be bootstrap ones - and thus i would suggest that you adopt a master page, and then you have the bootstrap formatting and classes included on all pages.

And as I stated before - you are MUCH better off to use a radiobuttion list. The reason here is MANY - and if you use a RadioButton list, then you can use code behind with GREAT ease to set that radio button list, and also if you have 2 or 15 choices, then the code behind becomes VERY easy.

So, I would ensure that the the bootstrap items are correctly included, and thus you not have to attempt to format this as you are.

but, you can and should be able to get this working:

```
      <style>
            .btn-check:checked + .btn-secondary, .btn-check:active + .btn-secondary, .btn-secondary:active, .btn-secondary.active, .show > .btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle {
              color: #fff;
              background-color: #80D2DA;
              border-color: #80D2DA;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 pt-lg-0 pt-2">
              <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" class="btn-check"  GroupName="Testing" Text="1"  />
               <label class="btn btn-secondary w-100 p-lg-3 p-3" for="RadioButton1">above 37&deg;C</label>
            </div>
```

And the above results in this:

[image]

and if I click on it, I get this:

[image]

however, you could and should have provided at lest a bit more markup.

As noted, a radio button list is FAR better, and will save you world poverty.

So, as suggested, this is a lot better:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" cssclass="MyRadio">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">below 36&deg;C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">36&deg;C - 37&deg;C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">above 37&deg;C</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Above gives this:

[image]

Not only is above rather clean, then in code behind, you can do this:

```
    Debug.Print("Index selected = " & RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex)
    Debug.Print("Value of Radio select = " & RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue)
    Debug.Print("Text of Radio select = " & RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text)
```

Output: (say first select)

```
Index selected = 0
Value of Radio select = 1
Text of Radio select = below 36°C
```

And the above also means you can in code behind set the value.

So you don't have to "create a group", and you don't have to drop or create each button seperate. And better yet, you can even drive the list for the radibo buttons from a table - all in all, you find this approach is less markup, works MUCH better with code behind (you can get the index value, the "value", or the text as per above - and even better, you can simple set the value or the index of that radio button list in code - and again, you only deal with one nice simple control.

But, if you going to toss in a style - then the above style should work, but as noted, those btn class do look like the bootstrap ones - so they should work assuming that you have bootstrap included in each page (and thus no need to include that style for the buttons).